# How do I verify commits on GitHub after I switched to using subkeys?

Tags: github, gnupg

I installed GnuPG on my main Windows computer, and created primary key. I was stupid at that time, and used the primary key as a signing key in git, and uploaded its public key to GitHub. These commits show as Verified on GitHub.

I later changed my mind and generated a new subkey, set it to the signing key for git. However, when I tried to upload the public key to GitHub, it says "Key already exists and Public key already exists" and fails. GitHub email, git email and gpg email seems to be the same.

Do I need to delete the public key for the primary key I uploaded on GitHub? Are there any other steps I need to do to make them Verified?

- env: windows 10, gpg 2.2.21, git 2.28.0.windows.1
- Unverified GPG key ID: 13BE71607A63CDF2
- Verified GPG key ID: AB61CEE479E4B09D
- When I `gpg --armor --export` both public keys looked the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this be deleting the existing key and uploading the new one. Previous commits were still verified after uploading the new key. I think this is because the old signing key is still present.

After doing this github will show multiple subkeys in the GPG keys section of your settings.

Comment: This definitely wasn't the case for me. Old commits are now "Unverified".

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this issue. Do **NOT** delete the old subkeys or primary keys from your local machine. You will need them later. I recommend reading the entire answer before proceeding.

### Create new local subkeys

1. Generate a new subkey using the same primary key as the expired key.
2. List all keys with `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`. Copy the id of the key you want to use.
3. Export public key in ASCII armor format with `gpg --armor --export keyid`, where `keyid` should be substituted with the copied key id of a signing subkey. Copy the output from the command, starting from `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` till `-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`. See note at the end of this answer for more information.

### Upload new subkeys to remote

4. In GitHub [user settings](https://github.com/settings/keys), you will find the old key with the expired subkey. Click on the `Delete` button to delete the old key from GitHub. We will now replace this key.
5. Click on the `New GPG key` button and add a title. Paste the ASCII armor format exported subkey and save by clicking on the `Add GPG key` button.

You should see expired keys, as well as active keys now. All previous commits on GitHub will show up as verified, and signed by an expired key. All new commits will show up as verified and signed by an active key.

#### Explanation

When you use `gpg --armor --export keyid`, GPG will export all public keys associated with the primary key related to the `keyid`.

For example, if you have a primary key with an expired subkey and a new subkey, then `gpg --armor --export keyid` will produce the public keys of:

1. Your primary key.
2. Your expired subkey.
3. Your new subkey.

Thus, when you paste the ASCII armor block into GitHub and add a new key, GitHub can now verify all commits signed with expired keys as well as new commits signed with active keys.

### If you have already deleted your old key from your local machine

Replace with your username and go to https://github.com/yourUserName.gpg and you will find the public key you need. Copy the ASCII armor block and paste it into a file and import it with `gpg --import filename.extension`. If you have deleted the old key from both your local machine AND GitHub, [your options are limited](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/229736/recover-lost-gpg-public-key).

---

**NOTE**: Do **not** use `gpg --armor --export keyid!`, note the `!` at the end, where `keyid` should be substituted with the copied key id of the signing key and a `!` suffix is added to signify a subkey. This will only export the public key of the primary key and only one subkey. This would be fine under other circumstances, but in this case you want the old expired subkeys as well, so leave off the `!`.

Comment: There are at least 2 contradictions in this answer.

Comment: @DavidLakatos Can you tell me what they are? Because I have been following these steps for a while now. And they work. Thank you.

Comment: You should clarify the "Do NOT delete the old subkeys" and "delete the old subkey" parts. I think you missed the information where the old subkeys should not be deleted from. Btw you could just modify the expiry date of the subkey and update it on GitHub.

Comment: @DavidLakatos Thank you for the input. It was helpful, and I have updated the answer to reflect it. Please let me know if you find anything else.