# How can I keep verification on github commits after moving to subkeys?

Tags: github, gnupg

I recently did a restructure of GPG subkeys so that I have separate keys for signing, auth and encryption:

```
sec   rsa2048/1B6B7842BBDF4ECE 2016-12-03 [SC]
      74CB4B430ABAB52DEFDECA481B6B7842BBDF4ECE
uid                 [ultimate] Viktor Hedefalk <hedefalk@gmail.com>
ssb   rsa2048/011A8AF0BDCADC7E 2016-12-03 [E]
ssb   rsa2048/67AD5595B594FB0F 2021-02-08 [S]
ssb   rsa2048/F62F31B2894C0560 2021-02-09 [A]
```

Problem arose because Github didn't consider my commits to be verified anymore. My options:

1. Add another entry with the new modified public key - couldn't do that without first deleting since it's actually the same key.
2. So I deleted the old public key armor and added a new entry from current gpg state. Now my old commits aren't verified but the new one is. This in contrast to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64591620/312873

How can I have both my historical and future commits verified? I'm confused by the output that github gives me here - both the unverified and verified are signed with 67AD5595B594FB0F if I understand this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to wait a few seconds/minutes for something to trigger at github. Just hit refresh now and all was dandy. Happy I took a screenshot or I would have thought I was imagining:

[image]